# How to change filenames on a big project without breaking it!

Tags: php, mysql

I have a big website from a client, whose files now need to be changed to english, for example: ststh.php should be sales.php.

Is there any tool to simplify this operation? I don't want to start changing names and then things start to break and not working...

The entire site is in php and mysql.

Any ideas on how to approach this?

Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: There are good tools for this: grep and patience.

Comment: Or, leave the files how they are, and use mod_rewrite?

Comment: Alongside @Jon's comment, you should probably audit all of the project files so you know what you've got. If you don't, you'll never know what is working, or what is broken.

Answer (score 4):

Use The PHP plugin of Eclipse, you can right-click -> refactor -> rename and everything will be fine! (Or it will tell you if something isn't).

Answer (score 1):

The best advice I can give is to change the file names, and a lot of software can search all open document, such as Notepad++ where you can do a find and replace on all open document, so you'll just find the old file name >> replace with the new file name.

Answer (score 1):

always go with tools. there are people who have gone through the trouble of writing tons of code to help developers with tasks like renaming files etc... so definitely use these tools. Eclipse is excellent, as Oltarus mentions, give that a try. Also, with knowledge of regular expressions you could get far. However to make sure nothing broke on the way you will not avoid thoroughly retesting every corner of the application.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in `Linux`, then follow this:

```
mv oldname.php newname.php

# search and replace the files (*.php) which has content oldname.php
find . -name "*.php" -exec sed -i -e 's/oldname.php/newname.php/' {} \;
```

If you are in `Windows`, then follow this:

Using eclipse you can easily do it. Please follow the steps in this link: http://www.eclipse-blog.org/eclipse-ide/using-find-and-replace-in-eclipse-ide.html